# How to maintain a cyclic relationship in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

How to maintain a cyclic relationship in mongodb? I have a case where I have  one more changes which are related to each other and querying any change should show all of the changes in the relation, let's say

```
query changeA --> should show changeA, changeB and changeC
query changeB --> should show changeA, changeB and changeC
query changeC --> should show changeA, changeB and changeC
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with a more real-world example of queries/results expected?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to advice the optimal solution when you didn't provide the structure of documents (ideally with some examples) and didn't share the usage patterns. When considering the data model, you have to answer these questions, among others:

- cardinality of the relationship, i.e. how many documents relate to each other
- how big (in bytes) is the average document, which together with the first point can limit usage of embedding documents due to MongoDB's document size limit
- do your documents change after inserting and if so, how often
- do relationships change over time
- do you want the structure optimalize for write or read

There are two sections in MongoDB documentation that cover this in depth, so it's good to go through:

- [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#data-modeling-embedding)
- [Data Model Examples and Patterns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/)